# Remove beginning and end from multiple MP4 files in bulk

Tags: macos, video-editing, mp4

I have several 100 videos that I need to remove the first 20 seconds and the last 30 seconds of.

Obviously not practical to do this one at a time. Can I automate this somehow, maybe in an OS X Automator script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you run *nix and Bash, [download an ffmpeg static build](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) for your operating system. Then, take the `ffmpeg` file and copy it to `/usr/bin/ffmpeg`.

```
sudo cp ~/Downloads/ffmpeg/ffmpeg /usr/bin/ffmpeg
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/ffmpeg
```

Now you can run this shell script in Bash — should be enough to copy-paste it in the folder where the videos are.

```
for f in *.mp4; do
    duration=$(ffmpeg -i "$f" 2>&1 | grep "Duration"| cut -d ' ' -f 4 | sed s/,//)
    length=$(echo "$duration" | awk '{ split($1, A, ":"); print 3600*A[1] + 60*A[2] + A[3] }' )
    trim_start=20
    trim_end=$(echo "$length" - 30 - "$trim_start" | bc)
    echo ffmpeg -ss "$trim_start" -i "$f" -c copy -map 0 -t "$trim_end" "${f%.mp4}-trimmed.mp4"
done
```

**Note:** Remove the `echo` statement to actually perform the commands. It would be good to test the generated commands first for accuracy. This would generate something like:

```
ffmpeg -ss 20 -i input.mp4 -c copy -map 0 -t 161.58 input-trimmed.mp4
```

What the script will do is calculate the total running time of the input, subtract the start time and the time you want to remove from the end, and then tell ffmpeg to do a stream-copy from your specified start time to the newly calculated end time. This will not harm the video and audio quality in any way. It should run within less then a few seconds even for large files.

To clarify, `-ss` sets the start time and `-c copy -map 0` will copy all video, audio and subtitle streams from the original to the cut version. `-t` sets the end time. See [this article on the FFmpeg Wiki](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Seeking%20with%20FFmpeg) for more info about seeking.

Answer (score 1):

If you're comfortable with command line, I would recommend [FFmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/)

```
ffmpeg -i file.mp4 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -ss 00:00:20.000 -t 00:00:30.000 output.mp4
```

Another option is a small shell script which loops through your files and runs a single-file FFmpeg job for each of them. Then again, I never used a Mac shell :)

```
for f in *.mp4; do ffmpeg -i $f -vcodec copy -acodec copy -ss 00:00:20.000 -t 00:00:30.000 output/$f; done
```

Hope this helps a little bit.

Comment: The OP needs to remove the last 30 seconds, not encode for 30 seconds, so your approach does not work. Also, the input syntax with `%d` is only supported for images (more specifically the [image2 demuxer](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#image2-2)).